# How to print the updated output

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I need help with my code because it doesn't print the updated output

For example:

```
Enter First name: Cid
Enter Middle name: RAZOR
Enter Last name: Kamisato
Enter number of subjects: 1
Please enter this valid subjects: ['CC1', 'CC2', 'CC3', 'CC4', 'CC5']
Please enter the subject: cc1
**** This is your info *****
First name is: Cid
Middle name is: RAZOR
Last name is: Kamisato
Your Selected Subjects are: ['cc1']
Do you want to change anything?(Y/N): y
1. Change First name
2. Change Middle name
3. Change Last name
4. Change number of subjects & change the subjects 
5. Exit
What do you want to change?: 1
Enter First name: CID
****** This is your updated info *******
First name is: CID
Middle name is: RAZOR
Last name is: Kamisato
Number of subjects: 1
Your Selected Subjects are: ['cc1']
Do you want to change anything?(Y/N): y
1. Change First name
2. Change Middle name
3. Change Last name
4. Change number of subjects & change the subjects 
5. Exit
What do you want to change?: 2
Enter Middle name: razor
****** This is your updated info *******
This is your first name: Cid
Middle name is: razor
Last name is: Kamisato
Number of subjects: 1
Your Selected Subjects are: ['cc1']
Do you want to change anything?(Y/N):
```

I want the updated CID name to be printed in the updated output and so on.

```
F_name = []
M_name = []
L_name = []
o_sub = []
no_sub = []
subjects = ['CC1', 'CC2', 'CC3', 'CC4', 'CC5']

name = input('Enter First name: ')
F_name.append(name)
mid_name = input('Enter Middle name: ')
M_name.append(mid_name)
last_name = input('Enter Last name: ')
L_name.append(last_name)


n_sub = int(input('Enter number of subjects: '))


 if n_sub <= 5:
    print(f'Please enter this valid subjects: {subjects}')
    no_sub.append(n_sub)
else:
    print('INVALID INPUT!!!')
    print('MAX IS 5!!!')

    exit()

for i in range(n_sub):
    sub = input('Please enter the subject: ')
    if sub.upper() in subjects:
        o_sub.append(sub)

    else:
        print('INVALID INPUT')
        break
print('**** This is your info *****')
print(f'First name is: {name}')
print(f'Middle name is: {mid_name}')
print(f'Last name is: {last_name}')
print(f'Your Selected Subjects are: {o_sub}')

while True:
    choice = input('Do you want to change anything?(Y/N): ')

     if choice.casefold() == 'y':
        print('1. Change First name')
        print('2. Change Middle name')
        print('3. Change Last name')
        print('4. Change number of subjects & change the subjects ')
        print('5. Exit')

    else:
         print('------THANK YOU FOR USING ME------!!!')
         exit()

    option1 = input('What do you want to change?: ')
    if option1 == '1':
        cf_name = str(input('Enter First name: '))
        F_name.clear()
        F_name.append(cf_name)
        print('****** This is your updated info *******')
        print(f'First name is: {cf_name}')
        print(f'Middle name is: {mid_name}')
        print(f'Last name is: {last_name}')
        print(f'Number of subjects: {n_sub}')
        print(f'Your Selected Subjects are: {o_sub}')

    elif option1 == '2':
        cm_name = input('Enter Middle name: ')
        M_name.clear()
        M_name.append(cm_name)
        print('****** This is your updated info *******')
        print(f'This is your first name: {name}')
        print(f'Middle name is: {cm_name}')
        print(f'Last name is: {last_name}')
        print(f'Number of subjects: {n_sub}')
        print(f'Your Selected Subjects are: {o_sub}')

     elif option1 == '3':
        cl_name = input('Enter Last name: ')
        L_name.clear()
        L_name.append(cl_name)
        print('****** This is your updated info *******')
        print(f'This is your first name: {name}')
        print(f'Middle name is: {mid_name}')
        print(f'Last name is: {cl_name}')
        print(f'Number of subjects: {n_sub}')
        print(f'Your Selected Subjects are: {o_sub}')

    elif option1 == '4':
        no_sub.clear()
        o_sub.clear()
        var = int(input('Enter the number of subjects: '))
        no_sub.append(var)
        if var <= 5:
             for i in range(var):
                sub1 = input('Please enter the subject: ')
                if sub1.upper() in subjects:
                    o_sub.append(sub1)

                else:
                    print('INVALID INPUT')
                    break
            print('****** This is your updated info *******')
            print(f'This is your first name: {name}')
            print(f'Middle name is: {mid_name}')
            print(f'Last name is: {last_name}')
            print(f'Number of subjects: {var}')
            print(f'Your Selected Subjects are: {o_sub}')

        else:
            print('INVALID INPUT')
            print('MAX IS 5!!')
            exit()

    elif option1 == '5':
        print('====== THANK YOU FOR USING ME ======')
        exit()
```

Comment: When you enter a new first name you're putting it into `cf_name`, but when you change the middle name you print `name`, not `cf_name`.

Comment: @Barmar i tried replacing it as cf_name but it has an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change one of the fields, you use a different variable than the one you use when printing out the info after changing other fields. E.g. you assign the new first name to `cf_name`, but the rest of the code expects it to be in `name`. You need to use the same variable consistently.

So change

```
    if option1 == '1':
        cf_name = str(input('Enter First name: '))
        F_name.clear()
        F_name.append(cf_name)
        print('****** This is your updated info *******')
        print(f'First name is: {cf_name}')
        print(f'Middle name is: {mid_name}')
        print(f'Last name is: {last_name}')
        print(f'Number of subjects: {n_sub}')
        print(f'Your Selected Subjects are: {o_sub}')
```

to

```
    if option1 == '1':
        name = str(input('Enter First name: '))
        F_name.clear()
        F_name.append(name)
        print('****** This is your updated info *******')
        print(f'First name is: {name}')
        print(f'Middle name is: {mid_name}')
        print(f'Last name is: {last_name}')
        print(f'Number of subjects: {n_sub}')
        print(f'Your Selected Subjects are: {o_sub}')
```

And change the other options similarly.

Comment: also how can i print the subjects into strings if the user enters the subjects?

Comment: The selected subject is `sub`, so print that.

Comment: by the way the code you gave is still not working it only prints the first entry and not the updated T.T

Comment: Every time the user enters a new name, you clear `F_name`, so you throw away all the other names.

Comment: You shouldn't be using multiple lists. Use a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains the info for a single student.

Comment: because when i dont throw the name the old name is still printed and i want the code to only print the updated names

Comment: You should replace the name in the list, not throw out all the old names.

Comment: I'm not sure why you even have those lists. You never put more than one name in the lists.